# Drag and Drop Jquery загрузка файлов - проблема с Firefox

Tags: jquery, drag-n-drop, dropzone

Добрый день!
Делаю загрузку файлов на ajax через drag and drop. 
В хроме все работает гуд, а вот в Mozilla ошибка.
Ошибка в строке, где элементу input[type="file"] пытаюсь назначить перемещенные файлы. А именно в строке

```
$('input[type="file"]').prop("files", dataTransfer.files) ;
```

Ошибка "TypeError: setting a property that has only a getter".

**Подскажите как правильно назначить элементу "file" перемещенные файлы?**

```
$('.drop').on({

'dragover dragenter': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
},

'drop': function(e) {

    var dataTransfer =  e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;
    var files = dataTransfer.files ;
    if(dataTransfer && files.length) {

        $('input[type="file"]').prop("files", dataTransfer.files) ;

    }

}
```

});